# ROR can't fine rake 10.0.4 despite being in vendor/cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rake, bundle

So this is annoying. When I put

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

into terminal, the following error occurs:

```
Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So I check with `bundle show rake`and it's there in:

/rails_projects/principia_app/vendor/cache/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4.

I've tried deleting the gemfile.lock and running `bundle install --path vendor/cache` and the same error occurs.

Also, I've tried doing it using gem 'rake','10.0.4' in the gemfile and without yielding the same results. I've updated all my gems too.

I haven't had any issues until now, and for some reason is happing today. Any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: Is it constrained by `gemspec` or `Gemfile`?

Comment: Have you updated any of your Gems?

Comment: I've tried doing it using  gem 'rake','10.0.4' in the gemfile and without with the same results. I've updated all my gems too.

Comment: try `gem install rake` to install latest version (10.0.4) of `rake`, and next `bundle update rake` to update the `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: tried that. still get 'Could not find rake-10.0.4 in any of the sources. Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.' when doing rake db:create.

Comment: What happened immediately prior to the error appearing?

Comment: I ran  the two commands 'rails generate scaffold post title:string body:text' and 'generate scaffold comment name:string body:text post:references'

Comment: is rake listed in Gem file? If not add an entry for it and try bundle install.

Comment: it's included in the Gemfile.

Comment: What OS are you using? I've received that error when not using a login shell in Linux. Try `/bin/bash --login` and then `rake`.

Comment: OK after a lot of grief I replaced the local copy with my reomote copy that I know is working and tried again still to no avail. After a lot of digging I found that the issue was because of the openssl issues with using https instead of http in my gemfile....wow. thanks so much for all the help though!!!

Comment: @Baldrik: with the exact same symptoms as the OP, your solution worked perfectly.

Comment: Same issue removed https made http still same :S any other solutions?